# find largest value in an array if value in first column matches specified value

Tags: arrays, excel, max, match, row

I'm trying to find the largest or max value in an array/range (E44:I205) among rows with values in column D (D44:D2015) that match a word. For instance:

```
D E F G H I
Cheetah Cat 0 1 2 3 4 
Tiger Cat 1 1 2 3 4 5
Dog 0 0 1 2 3
```

Among the rows with the word "*"&"cat", I want to find the max value. In this example, the formula should  = 5. I've tried the following formula, but it just returns the first instance of "cat" and the associated max value in that row.

```
=LARGE(IF($D$25:$D$205="*"&"cat",$E$44:$I$205,),1)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,E25:I205/(RIGHT(D25:D205,3)="cat"),1)
```

[image]

Comment: If you use FIND/SEARCH for Cat instead of right, does that force it to be a CSE?

Comment: Thank you so very much, Scott! For both being super fast and super helpful!

Comment: @ForwardEd no it does not.  I would have used that but the OP wanted strings ending in `"cat"`.  If it was contains I would have used `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())`

Comment: You are probably correct I was thinking search when right does not have the problems. @barryhoudini

Comment: could pop a `trim` or `clean` inside the `right` to eliminate potential trailing space, but that would be the Golden Cadillac of solutions.